# Build failed with android/support/v13/view/DragStartHelper

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am working on a project in which used

> compileSdkVersion 26
>   buildToolsVersion '25.0.0' and
>   compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'

Getting this error while building application earlier it was working fine.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v13/view/DragStartHelper$OnDragStartListener.class

Comment: Add your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 3):

You should add the following lines to you build.gradle file

```
configurations.all{ resolutionStrategy{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the following line from project.properties file in android folder and building again -

```
cordova.system.library.12=com.android.support:support-v13:26.+
```